# Generalised integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{y} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} e^{-x^2 - y^2} dx dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am having trouble understanding how to compute this integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{y} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} e^{-x^2 - y^2} \, dx \, dy$$
My idea is to consider the whole plane xy plane instead of the half of the positive quadrant. Then the integral would look like this. $$\frac{1}{8} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} e^{-x^2 - y^2} \, dx \, dy
$$

Of course we can change to polar coordinates and have $$\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} r^2 e^{-r^2} \, dr
$$
Here I am slightly at a loss and unsure of what to do? Any hint or suggestion? Thank you!

Note: Simply considering integration by parts and the Gaussian Integral we arrive at the desired answer. // as noted by @Benjamin Wang

Comment: By parts on $r\cdot re^{-r^2}$. Or use a result on the second moment of a Gaussian if you know it.

Comment: In polar coordinates the region of integration is $(0,\infty)\times (\frac {\pi} 4,\frac {\pi} 2)$

Comment: @BenjaminWang Yes I am trying the by parts and I am aware of the result and quite sure I should use it here but for some reason getting stuck, thank you!

Comment: @TeodorasPaura Did any of us answer your question?

Comment: @Gary yes, Benjamin Wang did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards the last part of your computation, integrating by parts we find,
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} r^2 e^{-r^2} \,dr= \int_{0}^{\infty} r D(-e^{-r^2}/2)\,dr=\bigg[-r e^{-r^2}/2\bigg]_0^{\infty}+ \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{-r^2}\,dr= 0+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$$
where at the last step we applied the [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 3):

If we perform the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x=yt$, we obtain
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } { \int_0^1 {y^2\sqrt {1 + t^2 } {\rm e}^{ - y^2(1 + t^2 )} {\rm d}t} \,{\rm d}y} .
$$
Interchanging the order of integration yields
$$
\int_0^1 {\sqrt {1 + t^2 } \int_0^{ + \infty } {y^2 {\rm e}^{ - y^2(1 + t^2 )} {\rm d}y} \,{\rm d}t} .
$$
Performing the change of integration variables from $y$ to $s$ via $s^2 = y^2(1 + t^2 )$ gives
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{1 + t^2 }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {s^2 {\rm e}^{ - s^2 } {\rm d}s}\, {\rm d}t}  = \int_0^1 {\frac{{\rm d}t}{{1 + t^2 }}}  \cdot \int_0^{ + \infty } {s^2 {\rm e}^{ - s^2 } {\rm d}s}  = \frac{\pi }{4} \cdot \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{4} = \frac{{\pi ^{3/2} }}{{16}}.
$$